# All the points lying on or inside the triangle formed by the points $A(1,3), B(5,6), C(-1,2)$ satisfy

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

All the points lying on or inside the triangle formed by the points $A(1,3), B(5,6), C(-1,2)$ satisfy

(A) $3x+2y\geq 0$

(B) $2x+y+1\geq 0$

(C) $2x+3y-12 \geq 0$

(D) $2x+11 \geq 11$

**My Approach:**

Equation of lines formed by given points are $3x-4y+9=0, x-2y+5=0, 2x-3y+8=0$ .

And Now let say point inside triangle be $P(\alpha, \beta)$.

Point $P$ lies inside the triangle formed by given lines

If $P$ and $A$ lies on same side of line $2x-3y+8=0$. i.e. $\; 2\alpha -3\beta +8\geq 0$

Also point $P$ and $B$ lies on same side of $x-2y+5=0$
$\;$i.e.$\; \alpha-2\beta+5\leq0$

And Point $P$ and $C$ lies on same side of $3x-4y+9=0$ i.e. $\; 3\alpha-4\beta+9\leq 0$

Now I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: Check if the triangle so formed lies completely to one side of any of the lines given in the options.

Comment: It looks like both options (A) and (B) are correct

Comment: You can simply verify if all vertices satisfy a given inequality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Let the line $L_1(x,y)=3x+2y-0$, then $L_1(1,3)=9>0, L_1(5,6)=15+12=27>0, L_3(-1,2)=-3+4=1>0$. This implies that all points inside ABC will satisfy $3x+2y \ge 0$

Similarly, you can check for other  given lines.